# Divide columns in df by another df value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-02', '2013-04-02'],
           'month': ['1','1','3','3','5'],
          'pmonth': ['1', '1', '2', '5', '5'],
          'duration': [30, 15, 20, 15, 30],
         'pduration': ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']})
```

I have to divide `duration` and `pduration` by value column of second dataframe where date and month of two `df` match. The second `df` is:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-01','2013-04-02','2013-04-03','2013-04-04', '2013-04-05'],
           'month': ['1','1','3','3','5'],
          'value': ['1', '1', '2', '5', '5'],
          })
```

The second `df` is grouped by date and month, so duplicate combination of date month won't be present in the second `df`.

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Comment: @coldspeed
I want to divide all values of duration and pduration by value column of second df if the date and month matches ,so in this case duration and pduration of first two rows must be divided by 1 as the value column in second df has value 1 for 2013-04-01 date and 1 month and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is necessary check if same `dtypes` of column `date` and `month` in both `DataFrames` and if numeric for columns for divide:

```
#convert to numeric
df1['pduration'] = df1['pduration'].astype(int)
df2['value'] = df2['value'].astype(int)

print (df1.dtypes)
date         object
month        object
pmonth       object
duration      int64
pduration     int32

print (df2.dtypes)
date     object
month    object
value     int32
dtype: object
```

Then `merge` with left join and divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['date', 'month'], how='left')

df[['duration_new','pduration_new']] = df[['duration','pduration']].div(df['value'], axis=0)
print (df)
         date month pmonth  duration  pduration  value  duration_new  \
0  2013-04-01     1      1        30         10    1.0          30.0   
1  2013-04-01     1      1        15         20    1.0          15.0   
2  2013-04-01     3      2        20         30    NaN           NaN   
3  2013-04-02     3      5        15         40    NaN           NaN   
4  2013-04-02     5      5        30         50    NaN           NaN   

   pduration_new  
0           10.0  
1           20.0  
2            NaN  
3            NaN  
4            NaN
```

For remove `value` column use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df[['duration_new','pduration_new']] = (df[['duration','pduration']]
                                             .div(df.pop('value'), axis=0))
print (df)
         date month pmonth  duration  pduration  duration_new  pduration_new
0  2013-04-01     1      1        30         10          30.0           10.0
1  2013-04-01     1      1        15         20          15.0           20.0
2  2013-04-01     3      2        20         30           NaN            NaN
3  2013-04-02     3      5        15         40           NaN            NaN
4  2013-04-02     5      5        30         50           NaN            NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the second df into the first df and then divide.

Consider the first df as `df1` and second df as `df2`

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['date', 'month'], how='left').fillna(1)
df1
         date month pmonth  duration pduration value
0  2013-04-01     1      1        30        10     1
1  2013-04-01     1      1        15        20     1
2  2013-04-01     3      2        20        30     1
3  2013-04-02     3      5        15        40     1
4  2013-04-02     5      5        30        50     1

df1['duration'] = df1['duration'] / df1['value']
df1['pduration'] = df1['pduration'] / df1['value']
df1.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can merge the two dataframes, where the date and month match the value column will be added to the first data frame. If there is no match it will represented by NaN. You can then do division operation. see code below

Assuming your second dataframe is df2, then

```
df3 = df2.merge(df, how = 'right')
for col in ['duration','pduration']:
    df3['new_'+col] = df3[col].astype(float)/df3['value'].astype(float)
df3
```

results in

```
date    month   value   pmonth  duration    pduration   newduration newpduration
0   2013-04-01  1   1   1   30  10  30.0    10.0
1   2013-04-01  1   1   1   15  20  15.0    20.0
2   2013-04-01  3   NaN 2   20  30  NaN NaN
3   2013-04-02  3   NaN 5   15  40  NaN NaN
4   2013-04-02  5   NaN 5   30  50  NaN NaN
```